# Unknown error in code

Tags: c++

Here's a link to the problem I am trying to solve: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=187

Here's a link to the solution of the problem: http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_cowfind.html

Here's my solution that I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n; int answer = 0;
    ifstream fin("cowfind.in");
    fin >> n;
    fin.close();
    int c = 0;

    //process for finding the number of possible outputs
    for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
    {
        if(n[i-1] == '(' && n[i] == '(') //increment the variable c for each pair of "hind" legs
            c++;
        if(n[i-1] == ')' && n[i] == ')') //increment answer for each pair of front legs
            answer++;
    }
    answer = answer * c; //number of pairs of hind legs * number of pairs of front legs
    ofstream fout("cowfind.out");
    fout << answer;
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

With that being said, what is wrong with my code? It keeps producing incorrect outputs, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: The first iteration of the loop, when `i` is `0`, what index will you use in `n[i - 1]` then?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh shoot I didn't see that. Sorry, I am an amateur coder looking to improve. Thanks for the help, but that still didn't fix it because after recompiling, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is incorrect. Lets look at this input: ))((. There is no solution here but your code will produce 1 solution.

Try to iterate the string searching for the first literal ((. Once found - iterate the rest of the string to find )) and add them to the solution sum.

Good luck!